# Get Data from DB every 5 sec and send it through AJAX to Views

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I need some help. I want to update Google Maps marker every 5 sec with data from db(mssql).

I have JsonResult witch returning tabel list :

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    JsonResult LoadDB()
    {
        EagleDBEntities db = new EagleDBEntities();

        return Json(db.Coordinates.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And my Ajax code in Views

```
        function getData() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Home/LoadDB",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {

                    $.each(data.items, function(item) {
                        alert('long:'+item.longitude +' lat:'+item.latitude);
                    });
                },
                error: function (response) {

                    alert('error');
                }
            });
```

In the and i get error alert ,  I am not receiving data from the database:(

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:7279/Home/LoadDB
```

Comment: Your immediate problem is the route isn't matching. We'll need to see your route config to diagnose why. FWIW, though, you should change the URL to `/Home/LoadDB` (note preceding slash), as this code will only work currently on the domain root. That said, you have JavaScript errors as well. In your success method, you reference `data` which is not defined (perhaps you meant `result`?) and even then, the response here will not have an `items` member, so that's going to fail too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it.

HomeController.cs:

```
    [HttpGet]
   public JsonResult LoadDB()
    {
        EagleDBEntities db = new EagleDBEntities();
        var cor = db.Lokalizacja          
           .Select(a => new
           {
               szerokosc = a.szerokosc,
               dlugosc = a.dlugosc
           });

        return Json(cor, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Maps.cshtml:

```
        function getData() {

        var counter = 0;
        interval = window.setInterval(function () {
            counter++;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "LoadDB",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                        moveMarker(item.szerokosc, item.dlugosc);

                    });
                },
                error: function (response) {

                    alert('eror');
                }
            });



            marker.setPosition(pos);
            if (counter >= 1000) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 10);




    };
```

Comment: The add anonymous method may not be necessary. I believe you would have received a "not authorized" exception if that were the case.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to setup a javascript timer like this one:

`setInterval(function(){ 
  getData();
 }, 3000);`

Comment: ok, thx but I have an error in the ajax  code, 
I am not receiving data from the database

Comment: Can you provide more details? Its a c# webservice? Can you paste the ajax error? or is just a null result response?

Comment: if you paste "http://localhost:7279/Home/LoadDB" to navigator will get the same response (404). You have to get the correct url from your running IIS express.